# How to check if any checkbox of a form is checked and how to tell if none is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I looked everywhere but none of the suggestions on here seem to work for me.
How can I check with Jquery if any checkbox on a form is checked (and if, activate a button) and how can I deactivate a button if none of the checkboxes are checked?
So far I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//form-1

if ($('#form-1 input=[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
$('#form-1 a.green-btn').removeClass('inactive');
} else {
$('#form-1 a.green-btn').addClass('inactive');
}

</script>
```

Where am I wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems in JQuery selector (should be `input[type="checkbox"]`). However, your code can be rewritten in a short way:

```
$("#form-1 a.green-btn").toggleClass("inactive", !$("#form-1 :checkbox:checked").length);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yTPKL/

**UPDATE.** You can also check the state of checkboxes in the on `change` event of checkboxes:

```
$("#form-1 :checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $("#form-1 a.green-btn").toggleClass("inactive", !$("#form-1 :checkbox:checked").length);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yTPKL/1/

Comment: thanks! you gave me the right pointer! what I needed is that:$('#form-1 input').each(function() {
  $(this).change(function(){
    $("#form-1 a.green-btn").toggleClass("inactive", $("#form-1 :input:checked").length > 0);
  });
});

Comment: @NicoleLoyalWindham There is no need to use `each`. Have a look at the answer update.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your check box are checked by following

```
var check=$('<checkbox-element>').attr('checked');
```

this will return true/false.
there after you can write your code depending on the condition.